# How to exclude some rows based on user id in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have 3 tables: `posts`, `votes` and `users`. I want to exclude that posts that were already voted by the current user (Auth::user()->id). How should I achieve that? I tried with this code:

```
 $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $posti = Post::with('user')
        ->whereDoesntHave("votes")
        ->whereBetween('posts.created_at', array(Carbon::now()->subHours(48), Carbon::now()))
        ->orderBy('posts.created_at', 'DESC')
        ->orderByVotes()
        ->take(20)
        ->get();
```

Comment: this will give you the Posts without any votes not Users who does nto have votes. So for that put where condition to check the in the votes table with user id.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if posts don't have votes from the logged in user using votes relation and callback function. To achieve this use the code below:

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
Post::with('votes')
    ->whereDoesntHave('votes', function ($query) use ($userId) {
        $query->where('user_id', $userId);
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can also use the relationship in if condition to check if logged user already voted or not like:

```
$user = Auth::user()->id;
@if($user->votes)

@else
```